# Google Cloud Endpoint framework in python with FireO

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm using App engine standard.

I want to use Google Cloud endpoint framework in python I read the documentation about this I found that endpoint only support **python 2.x** But as I know python 2 is going to end on this year, isn't it ?

Another thing I want to use Google cloud Firestore as a backend for endpoint There is library available for Firestore named [FireO](https://github.com/octabytes/fireo) but it work in **python 3.x** can I use it with Firestore. Can I install library which work in python 3 is there any way ?

Please let me know thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/python/get-started-frameworks-python#before-you-begin) it is clear that Python 3.x is not supported by Cloud Endpoints Framework.

A possible solution would be to use [Cloud Endpoints on **App Engine flexible environment**](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/get-started-app-engine#top_of_page). This method employs the [Extensible Service Proxy (ESP)](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/glossary#extensible_service_proxy), which is used in Cloud Endpoints for APIs using OpenAPI or gRPC running on an instance in the App Engine flexible environment, instead of Cloud Endpoints Frameworks for App Engine standard.

- [Here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/choose-endpoints-option), you may find information about the Endpoints options available, so that you can decide which one is appropriate for you.
- Additionally, [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/frameworks-extensible-service-proxy) you may find an overview about the differences in comparing Extensible Service Proxy and Cloud Endpoints Frameworks.

Simultaneously, I created a [**Public Issue**](https://issuetracker.google.com/145194043) on your behalf, in order for the issue to get resolved.

- This issue report has been forwarded to the Cloud Endpoints engineering team so that they may investigate it, but there is no ETA for a resolution at this time. Future updates regarding this issue will be provided [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/145194043).
- You may “star” the Public Issue, so that it gets more visibility and also add your email address to the “CC” section, in order to receive updates on the case.